# How do you earn medals? How much XP do they give?

Tags: overwatch

**At the end of the game, how are medals awarded?**

As a secondary, what is the relation between bronze silver and gold medals, and how much experience do they reward?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The medals are just for the first, second, and third place for each category (Eliminations, Objective Kills, Objective Time, Damage Done, and Healing Done) other than Deaths on your team. The bonus XP is 50 for a bronze medal, 100 for a silver medal, and 150 for a gold medal. Note that you can only receive a single bonus, matching your most valuable medal.

Comment: What are the categories?

Comment: @JamesCW Updated!

Comment: @SaintWacko So just to be sure, you're saying that if you did the second most damage on your team, you'd receive the silver medal for that category?

Comment: Oh, wow. That's not what I assumed at all. Figured there were preset thresholds. Cool.

Comment: I've never seen a medal awarded for Deaths.  There's a reason it has a skull sign and not a medal outline.

Comment: @Dante That's how I understand it, yes.

Comment: @Powerlord Oh, you're right. I added the categories later and didn't think about that.

Comment: Worth adding that the rewards are not cumulative, you get whichever is highest. For example, if you get three gold medals, you get 150 exp, not 450.

Comment: Definitely no threshold.  I once got gold with 3 eliminations after a particularly pathetic loss.  Also, two people can get gold if they tie.  (I know this because in a different game another team member got a card for "four gold" in a game where I got two.)

Answer (score -5):

Medals are based off how well you are doing compared to your average stats on a map and objective and are adjusted to the time the answer that it is first second and third place is false becuase muilple can get a gold medal in a match without tying in those stats with other best player becuase your whole team can get gold medals for eliminations and objective times

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, but I'm pretty sure this is wrong. Any time I've talked to my teammates about medals, it's been entirely consistent with the accepted answer, including needing to tie to both get gold. If you're certain this is correct, you'll need to provide enough evidence to convince us that the other answer is wrong. In the meantime, expect downvotes.

Answer (score -6):

As @[SaintWacko](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264742/how-do-you-earn-medals/264743#264743) has stated, the Overwatch player statistics for medals are equations that function. See below for equations:

`( elim + objk + objt + dd + hd )`

- Eliminations +
- Objective Kills +
- Objective Time +
- Damage Done +
- Healing Done

[image: See Img]

Comment: Each category is awarded a medal separately, I'm not sure what you're trying to say here.

Comment: to which cat are you speaking of? I was giving a visual to what SaintWacko has answered which is the correct answer. If you want to talk categories, then we can say many of things, but we are talking at end game and medals. Not overall or whatever your trying to get at.
Simple math man

Comment: As I said, I have no idea what you're trying to say. You might want to reword your answer because it's unintelligible as it is. Not just that, this seems completely unrelated to the other answer.

Comment: I also have no idea what you're talking about. What/where is that image from?