# Why do I get tons of medals in custom games against AI?

Tags: overwatch

I like to practise in custom games, alone with 11 bots. Sometimes I have low stats, such as 6 eliminations, but I repeatedly get 4 gold medals. Why is this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you earn medals?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264742/how-do-you-earn-medals)

Comment: that one doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The AI is unable to earn medals. Thus, if you are the only human player on your team, you are guaranteed to get a gold medal for every nonzero stat you have.

Comment: that sucks. why can't ai earn medals? do we get experience in custom games?

Comment: @JimThio No, you do not get experience in custom games. You get a small amount in the vs AI game mode, a little more in the weekly brawl, and the most from Quick Play and Competitive play. You also get +20% experience for queuing with someone else.