# Why do you get a gold medal for 0:00 objective time?

Tags: overwatch

Quite often in a game you'll noticed that you'll have gold objective time, despite the fact that you have 0 seconds of it. Is there a criteria needed for this (i.e. do you have to spend less than 1 second on the point), or is it randomly generate, and, if so, how is the gold medal awarded?

Comment: In addition to the answer you can also get a gold medal in bot games because [bots can't be awarded medals](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281761/why-do-i-get-tons-of-medals-in-custom-games-against-ai?rq=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stats only show integer amounts of seconds. If you spend less than one second of objective time, it will be recorded correctly, but only shown as 0:00.

Comment: And will 0.5 seconds of objective time round to 1 second or will it only ever round down?

Comment: If I know videogames, it'll always round down, but I've never tested this

Comment: If they specifically said it's an Integer then it will never round up. Integers could be described as "the full parts" of a number. If they're all integers: 1,23 = 1,99 = 1

Comment: The technical terms would be "floored" or "truncated", which have the same effect.